# Specifications JPA - Inner + where clause

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data-jpa, specifications

I have to join two tables and filter the result with a Where with Specifications and JPA. But I'm not very familiar with it.

The tables are for example:

```
public class A {

 private Long id;

 private Long secondId;


 ...
}


public class daughterA {

 @JoinColumn (name = "id")
 private Long idA;

 ...
}
```

and the WHERE is to be applied on secondId.

Thank you all for the help, I apologize for any inaccuracies, i'm beginning with these technologies.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, your Join seems to be a one To Many join so you should make it as it is :

- add the One annotation in the parent class being mapped by the name of the instance of it in the other class, this notation covers a Set or a List of objects of the daughters class
- add the ManyToOne annotation in the daughter class, a daughter can only have one mother, and idA is not Long but it refers to the parent class it's in fact a foreign key

```java
    public class A{ 

     @Id
     private Long id;

     private Long secondId;

     @OneToMany(mappedBy="idA")
     private Set<daughterA > daughters;

     ...
    }


    public class daughterA {

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn (name = "id")
     private A idA;

     ...
    }
```

and for the where clause :

```
TypedQuery<Country> query =
  em.createQuery("SELECT d FROM daughterA d WHERE d.idA.secondId = :secondId ", Country.class);
  A results = query.setParameter("secondId",sencondId).getSingleResult();
```